# Angular: How can I use Velocity.js within my Angular application?

Tags: angularjs, velocity.js

I have used [velocity.js](http://velocityjs.org/) in my own personal web *sites* but never within an angular application. I'm not an angular developer (yet) so please bear with me.

I am following the README file on the [angular-velocity github page](https://github.com/cgwyllie/angular-velocity). But when I run my application, I am getting an error that I am missing the module.

Here is what my module declaration looks like:

```
var appModule = angular.module('app.module', ['module-one', 'module-two', 'angular-velocity']);

...
```

The error I get now is:

```
Module 'angular-velocity' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
```

Further reading I see this:

> When installing from npm, it is assumed that VelocityJS will be installed and loaded before Angular Velocity.

Ok, so I installed (via npm) the velocity library. How do I include that in my list of dependancies?

Also this:

> angular-velocity assumes that the Angular core and the additional ngAnimate module is loaded

So does that mean I need something like this?

```
var appModule = angular.module('app.module', ['module-one', 'module-two', 'ngAnimate', 'angular-velocity']);
```

But in the example, all that is listed is `angular-velocity`.

Nowhere in my project do I see individual script tags. I am assuming the project just reads the dependancies and grabs them from the `package.json` file? (Completely guessing).

**This does not happen:**

```
<script src="bower_components/velocity/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/velocity/velocity.ui.min.js"></script
<script src="bower_components/angular-velocity/angular-velocity.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

You can include velocity using CDN

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.3/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/velocity/1.2.3/velocity.min.js"></script>
```

or using bower

```
bower install velocity
```

and add its references in the header from default folder `bower_components`.

If instead you use `npm` you can use:

`npm install velocity-animate`

and add its references in the header from default folder `node_modules`.

Comment: I tried adding the script to index.html but still getting error: `Property 'velocity' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'`. I am new to angular too. I have installed `npm install velocity-animate` but how should I do the import? I think something like `import velocity from velocity-animate` but I don't finish to figure it out. I import it of course on the `.ts` file I use veolicy in.